# Visual Basic Mob AI Wander?

Tags: vb.net

Right now my mob just moves around randomly, I need it to walk in strait lines like 30 pixels then turn, but I don't really know where to start...

```
    Function mob()
        Application.DoEvents()
        Randomize()
        Dim value As Integer = CInt(Int((4 * Rnd()) + 1))
        If value = 1 Then
        ElseIf value = 2 Then
    If Me.mob2.Location.Y < 549 Then
        Me.mob2.Location = New Point(Me.mob2.Location.X, Me.mob2.Location.Y + 1)
    End If
        ElseIf value = 3 Then
    If Me.mob2.Location.X > 12 Then
        Me.mob2.Location = New Point(Me.mob2.Location.X - 1, Me.mob2.Location.Y)
    End If
        ElseIf value = 4 Then
    If Me.mob2.Location.X < 750 Then
        Me.mob2.Location = New Point(Me.mob2.Location.X + 1, Me.mob2.Location.Y)
    End If
        End If

End Function

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    mob()
End Sub
```

Comment: Use GraphicsPath. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: @Meatie Are you after help with the graphics? Or maybe structuring your classes\events, e.g. `_Tick` could call `Me.mob2.Move()`? Or just an algorithm for a straight line?

Comment: I didn't know about the .Move() thing, ill look into it, Im not into graphics at least yet, Thanks for the help tho. For the question I want the mob to move in straight lines for like 20 pixels not jumping, Moving one pixel at a time really fast so it seams real.